# Executing tasks in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Ok, so basically I have a bunch of tasks (10) and I want to start them all at the same time and wait for them to complete. When completed I want to execute other tasks. I read a bunch of resources about this but I can't get it right for my particular case...

Here is what I currently have (code has been simplified):

```
public async Task RunTasks()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        new Task(async () => await DoWork()),
        //and so on with the other 9 similar tasks
    }


    Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task =>
    {
        task.Start();
    });

    Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(done =>
    {
        //Run the other tasks
    });
}

//This function perform some I/O operations
public async Task DoWork()
{
    var results = await GetDataFromDatabaseAsync();
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        await ReadFromNetwork(result.Url);
    }
}
```

So my problem is that when I'm waiting for tasks to complete with the `WhenAll` call, it tells me that all tasks are over even though none of them are completed. I tried adding `Console.WriteLine` in my `foreach` and when I have entered the continuation task, data keeps coming in from my previous `Task`s that aren't really finished.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I suspect in all this you have a `Task<Task>` somewhere (calling the Task constructor directly is somewhat suspect) and you really want to await the inner task. Can you use `Task.Run` instead of the Task constructor/Start? `Task.Run` will do the unwrapping for you.

Comment: So you think I should do: 
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Run(()=> DoWork())
}

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You should almost never use the `Task` constructor directly. In your case that task only fires the actual task that you can't wait for.

You can simply call `DoWork` and get back a task, store it in a list and wait for all the tasks to complete. Meaning:

```
tasks.Add(DoWork());
// ...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

However, async methods run synchronously until the first await on an uncompleted task is reached. If you worry about that part taking too long then use `Task.Run` to offload it to another `ThreadPool` thread and then store **that** task in the list:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork()));
// ...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: By *run synchronously until the first await* did you want to mean they would actually run async only when we called `Task.WhenAll`? Thanks!

Comment: @Alisson I was more referring to the synchronous part of `DoWork` and not the code calling it.

Comment: @i3arnon, as you said, However, async methods run synchronously until the first await on an uncompleted task is reached. ----              
           SO here can I use "await task.delay(5).ConfigureAwait(false); statement as a first line in my DoWork() method?  to return the main thread and start the Threadpool Thread for to execute remianing code in the method, ? Please advise.

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed you don't need `Task.Delay`. You have `Task.Yield` exactly for that purpose. But as I see it using `Task.Run` is better in that case because it's more explicit about "firing up" a new task.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to run those task's parallel in different threads using TPL you may  need something like this:

```
public async Task RunTasks()
{
    var tasks = new List<Func<Task>>
    {
       DoWork,
       //...
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.AsParallel().Select(async task => await task()));

    //Run the other tasks
}
```

These approach parallelizing only small amount of code: the queueing of the method to the thread pool and the return of an uncompleted `Task`. Also for such small amount of task parallelizing can take more time than just running asynchronously. This could make sense only if your tasks do some longer (synchronous) work before their first await.

For most cases better way will be:

```
public async Task RunTasks()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(new [] 
    {
        DoWork(),
        //...
    });
    //Run the other tasks
}
```

To my opinion in your code:

1. You should not wrap your code in `Task` before passing to `Parallel.ForEach`.
2. You can just `await` `Task.WhenAll` instead of using `ContinueWith`.

Comment: An inspiring code snippet, perhaps the best on the net which combines task parallel with async using PLINQ.

Comment: As a suggestion: using dotNet 4.7+ or Core, you no longer need to the `new[] {}`.  Instead you can just pass multiple tasks such as `WhenAll(DoWork(), ....)`.

Answer (score 10):

Essentially you're mixing two incompatible async paradigms; i.e. `Parallel.ForEach()` and `async-await`.

For what you want, do one or the other.  E.g. you can just use `Parallel.For[Each]()` and drop the async-await altogether.  `Parallel.For[Each]()` will only return when all the parallel tasks are complete, and you can then move onto the other tasks.

The code has some other issues too:

- you mark the method async but don't await in it (the await you do have is in the delegate, not the method);
- you almost certainly want `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on your awaits, especially if you aren't trying to use the results immediately in a UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

The `DoWork` method is an asynchronous I/O method. It means that you don't need multiple threads to execute several of them, as most of the time the method will asynchronously wait for the I/O to complete. One thread is enough to do that.

```
public async Task RunTasks()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        DoWork(),
        //and so on with the other 9 similar tasks
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    //Run the other tasks            
}
```

You should almost [never use the `Task` constructor](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) to create a new task. To create an asynchronous I/O task, simply call the `async` method. To create a task that will be executed on a thread pool thread, use `Task.Run`. You can read [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) for a detailed explanation of `Task.Run` and other options of creating tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just also add a try-catch block around the Task.WhenAll

NB: An instance of System.AggregateException is thrown that acts as a wrapper around one or more exceptions that have occurred. This is important for methods that coordinate multiple tasks like Task.WaitAll() and Task.WaitAny() so the AggregateException is able to wrap all the exceptions within the running tasks that have occurred.

```
try
{ 
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());  
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{ 
    foreach (Exception inner in ex.InnerExceptions)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception type {0} from {1}", inner.GetType(), inner.Source));
    }
}
```