# run parallel tasks in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, multitasking

I'm developing a software which I need to make parallel tasks.
For example here is my `task1`:

```
Task t1 = new Task(()=>
{
    //Do Some Codes
});
```

And I have more tasks which have the same code as `task1`:

```
Task t2 = new Task(()=>
{
    //Do task1 codes
});

Task t3 = new Task(()=>
{
    //Do task1 codes
});

t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
```

I also have a timer so that I can check these tasks works and do the processes faster. But it won't change and they have the same time as one task.

Now I want to know how I can run parallel tasks and give me faster result.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean parallel? `Task` is a single operation, performed asynchronously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing tasks in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375696/executing-tasks-in-parallel)

Comment: you can achieve this by async function

Comment: This series of readings is very useful for everyone dealing with tasks and stuff: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have two functions and you want to execute them parallel. I think there are two ways you can do that:

1: Using Task Parallel Library-

```
private void Function1()
{
    //do work
}

private void Function2()
{
    //do work
}

private void RunParallel()
{
    Parallel.Invoke(Function1, Function2);
}
```

2: Running each function in separate threads-

```
private void Function1()
{
    //do work
}

private void Function2()
{
    //do work
}

private void RunParallel()
{
    ThreadStart ts1 = new ThreadStart(Function1);
    ThreadStart ts2 = new ThreadStart(Function2);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(ts1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(ts2);

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use "Multiple Threads" for calling your Methods or calling async methods.
That should help.

**For More Info:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

And the voted answer on this question can be helpful too

[What is the difference between asynchronous programming and multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading)