# Task does not work when with return value with Timeout

Tags: c#

I want to create a task to return value that with 5 seconds timeout (desktop application).

Here is my sample code:

```
public async Task<int> Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        var _result = await (new Task<int>(() =>
        {
            int i = 1;
            ///some code
            return i;
        })).WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        return _result;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    catch {
        return -2;
    }
}
```

The framework I am using is .Net8.

Why does the task never start even if I add a break point that always return a TimeoutException.

Comment: Please prefer Task.Run over creating a new Task via its constructor.

Comment: @PeterCsala All right, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As you can see right here, task actually executing properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IM6k.png)

The only think u need to do, hm so, i guess it is just running this task. Because this is a task btw .-.

[After that u should be fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T8sW.png) <- This picture

About more information because i use Task.Run() only as example, use in parallel couse a lot of cases needs it: [Executing tasks in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375696/executing-tasks-in-parallel)

Hope it helps